# Java array adding algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, linkedhashset

currently i have this set of data inside a sorted array from lowest price to highest price.

```
Line 1 in the user container need Basic( Special : true) - Ship name: Titanic

The Price is: 10.0 Capacity: 300.0

Line 1 in the user container need Basic( Special : true) - Ship name: Ace

The Price is: 10.0 Capacity: 400.0

Line 1 in the user container need Basic( Special : true) - Ship name: Adda

The Price is: 5.0 Capacity: 130.0

Line 1 in the user container need Basic( Special : true) - Ship name: mutha

The Price is: 6.0 Capacity: 350.0

Line 1 in the user container need Basic( Special : true) - Ship name: spade

The Price is: 10.0 Capacity: 450.0
```

The **result** of the first sorted array**[5.0,6.0,10.0,10.0,10.0]** each data is paired with the ship name.

**My GOAL(create a new string array):**
[Adda,mutha,spade,ace,Titanic]
Adda is the cheapest follow by mutha.For spade, ace and titanic, they are sorted by capacity since they have the same price
Here is my code

```
Map<Ships, Double> sortedMap = sortByComparator(shipsarray);
            LinkedHashSet<String> uniqueStrings = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
            double tempprice=0,tempcap=0;
            String tempship = null;

            for (Map.Entry<Ships, Double> entry : sortedMap.entrySet()) {//loop for fill in
                if((double)entry.getValue() == tempprice){
                    if(entry.getKey().getAvailableCapacityForType(user.getContainers().get(i).getClass())>tempcap){
                        System.out.println(uniqueStrings);
                        uniqueStrings.remove(tempship);
                        uniqueStrings.add(entry.getKey().getship().getShipName());
                        uniqueStrings.add(tempship);
                        System.out.println(uniqueStrings);
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println(uniqueStrings);
                        uniqueStrings.add(entry.getKey().getship().getShipName());
                    }
                }
                else{
                    uniqueStrings.add(entry.getKey().getship().getShipName());
                    tempprice = (double)entry.getValue();
                    tempship = entry.getKey().getship().getShipName();
                    tempcap = entry.getKey().getAvailableCapacityForType(user.getContainers().get(i).getClass());
                }



            }
```

currently the outcome is **[Adda, mutha, spade, Titanic]**
missing ace.

Thanks for helping

Comment: There are no arrays in your question.

Comment: I suggest that you learn how to use a debugger to step through your code to see what it is doing. Also, where are you using an array?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to implement a custom comparator and use it with Arrays.sort() to get the wanted ordering. Something like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Ship a = new Ship("A", 5, 100);
        Ship b = new Ship("B", 6, 400);
        Ship c = new Ship("C", 6, 300);
        Ship[] ships = {a,c,b};

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ships));

        Arrays.sort(ships, new Comparator<Ship>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Ship o1, Ship o2) {
                if (o1.price < o2.price) return -1;
                if (o1.price > o2.price) return 1;
                else return o1.capacity > o2.capacity ? -1 : 1;
            }
        });

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ships));

    }

    public static class Ship {
        public final String name;
        public final int price;
        public final int capacity;
        public Ship(String name, int price, int capacity) {
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
            this.capacity = capacity;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("(%s | price=%d, capacity=%d)", name, price, capacity);
        }
    }

}
```